# Splitting CamelCase

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

This is all asp.net c#.

I have an enum

```
public enum ControlSelectionType 
{
    NotApplicable = 1,
    SingleSelectRadioButtons = 2,
    SingleSelectDropDownList = 3,
    MultiSelectCheckBox = 4,
    MultiSelectListBox = 5
}
```

The numerical value of this is stored in my database. I display this value in a datagrid.

```
<asp:boundcolumn datafield="ControlSelectionTypeId" headertext="Control Type"></asp:boundcolumn>
```

The ID means nothing to a user so I have changed the boundcolumn to a template column with the following.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Enum.Parse(typeof(ControlSelectionType), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ControlSelectionTypeId").ToString()).ToString()%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

This is a lot better... However, it would be great if there was a simple function I can put around the Enum to split it by Camel case so that the words wrap nicely in the datagrid.

Note: I am fully aware that there are better ways of doing all this. This screen is purely used internally and I just want a quick hack in place to display it a little better.

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value.ToLower())

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Indeed a regex/replace is the way to go as described in the other answer, however this might also be of use to you if you wanted to go a different direction

```
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Reflection;
```

...

```
    public static string GetDescription(System.Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
```

this will allow you define your Enums as

```
public enum ControlSelectionType 
{
    [Description("Not Applicable")]
    NotApplicable = 1,
    [Description("Single Select Radio Buttons")]
    SingleSelectRadioButtons = 2,
    [Description("Completely Different Display Text")]
    SingleSelectDropDownList = 3,
}
```

Taken from

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-412868.html

Comment: +1 Great answer, I will probably use the regular expression answer as it's quicker and easier, however, this is a far better solution and so gets the accepted.

Comment: I have seen many answers on enum attributes, but this looks the cleanest!

Comment: clever, but it's a lot more work than a simple static regex function.  I'm not sure I agree with "cleanest" or "quicker" or "easier".  Cleverist?  for sure.

Comment: This only works if you have control over that enum, but I would rather have full control over the display code rather than assume that the enum values will be sanely spelled.

Answer (score 161):

I used:

```
    public static string SplitCamelCase(string input)
    {
        return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "([A-Z])", " $1", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();
    }
```

Taken from http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/09/27/426087.aspx

vb.net:

```
Public Shared Function SplitCamelCase(ByVal input As String) As String
    Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "([A-Z])", " $1", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim()
End Function
```

Here is a [dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2aiv7g) for online execution of the c# code.

Comment: Simple way to accomplish the camel case part ... the other approach is better for more customization. Thanks @Tillito

Comment: I tweaked the regular expression a little to "(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])".  This results in ProductID being converted to Product ID instead of Product I D.  It specifies that the upper case letter must be preceded by a lower case letter (note the lookbehind operator).  It also eliminates the need for the trim.

Comment: Hey Ben, why don't you put that as an answer. Having a different (and more sophisticated) regex constitutes a new answer mate!

Comment: As an addition to Ben's helpful comment, I should mention that you can also split something like "HELLOWorld" into "HELLO World" using the regular expression: (?<=[A-Z])([A-Z])(?=[a-z])

Comment: I kept the same idea, but used [A-Z]+ with a string trim.  This kept multiple caps together like Ben's but without using the lookbehind operator (which didn't work in JavaScript where I was using this technique).

Comment: To avoid the overhead of lookahead/behind:
Regex.Replace(text, "(\\S)([A-Z])", "$1 $2")
This also does not require trim.

Comment: I combined Ben Mills' and giangurgolo's expressions:
Regex.Replace(input, @"((?<=[A-Z])([A-Z])(?=[a-z]))|((?<=[a-z]+)([A-Z]))", @" $0", RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();

Answer (score 30):

This regex `(^[a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+)` can be used to extract all words from the camelCase or PascalCase name. It also works with abbreviations anywhere inside the name.

- `MyHTTPServer` will contain exactly 3 matches: `My`, `HTTP`, `Server`
- `myNewXMLFile` will contain 4 matches: `my`, `New`, `XML`, `File`

You could then join them into a single string using `string.Join`.

```
string name = "myNewUIControl";
string[] words = Regex.Matches(name, "(^[a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+)")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
string result = string.Join(" ", words);
```

---

As @DanielB noted in the comments, that regex won't work for numbers (and with underscores), so here is an improved version that **supports any identifier with words, acronyms, numbers, underscores** (slightly modified @JoeJohnston's version), see [online demo (fiddle)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MTfhP9):

```regex
([A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+|[0-9]+|[a-z]+)
```

Extreme example: `__snake_case12_camelCase_TLA1ABC` → `snake`, `case`, `12`, `camel`, `Case`, `TLA`, `1`, `ABC`

Comment: I like it. However, we live in modern times. Hence: `@"(^\p{Ll}+|\p{Lu}+(?!\p{Ll})|\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)"` It’s also important to note that this won’t do numbers at all, even though they’re valid in identifiers.

Comment: Simple yet perfect!

Comment: I needed a slight change to "(^[a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+|[0-9\.*]+|[a-z]+)" "ITPortfolio12v2.0.13BMS" results in "IT Portfolio 12 v 2.0.13 BMS" hth someone

Comment: (^[\p{Ll}]+|[\p{Lu}\p{N}]+(?![\p{Ll}])|\p{P}?[\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]+) generalized ot work with Unicode words.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/SyZzmm

Comment: In your new and improved version you should be able to remove the '^[a-z]+' since you also have '[a-z]+' :P

Comment: @Kim Oh, thanks for pointing that out. It should be fixed now

Answer (score 21):

Tillito's answer does not handle strings already containing spaces well, or Acronyms. This fixes it:

```
public static string SplitCamelCase(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", " $1", RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: credit goes to Tillito, provider of the original answer, and Ben Mills, who suggested the improvement in a comment. Since it's an improved answer and none of them posted or edited it, it deserves a separate answer. Would have saved me half an hour of debugging if it wasn't buried under comments to begin with.

Comment: Fails with the simple test case "SMSMessage" (expected: "SMS Message", actual: "SMSMessage").

Comment: "SMSMessage" isn't actually camelCase, according to most guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526107/acronyms-in-camelcase

Answer (score 15):

If C# 3.0 is an option you can use the following one-liner to do the job:

```
Regex.Matches(YOUR_ENUM_VALUE_NAME, "[A-Z][a-z]+").OfType<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).Aggregate((acc, b) => acc + " " + b).TrimStart(' ');
```

Comment: This doesn't handle Acroynms in the text like AMACharter, returns 'Charter' not 'AMA Charter'.

Comment: Although modifications to handle such a case would be easy (think of prepending something like ([A-Z]*) and slightly modifying the code), from what I recall of Microsoft's coding guidelines the use of such all-caps acronyms is discouraged, and in all-caps acronyms general acronyms should be avoided if longer than 2 letters.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. "CamelCase" becomes "Camel" and not "Camel Case".

Answer (score 10):

Here's an extension method that handles numbers and multiple uppercase characters sanely, and also allows for upper-casing specific acronyms in the final string:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace System
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension methods for the string data type
    /// </summary>
    public static class ConventionBasedFormattingExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Turn CamelCaseText into Camel Case Text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <remarks>Use AppSettings["SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords"] to specify a comma-delimited list of words that should be ALL CAPS after split</remarks>
        /// <example>
        /// wordWordIDWord1WordWORDWord32Word2
        /// Word Word ID Word 1 Word WORD Word 32 Word 2
        /// 
        /// wordWordIDWord1WordWORDWord32WordID2ID
        /// Word Word ID Word 1 Word WORD Word 32 Word ID 2 ID
        /// 
        /// WordWordIDWord1WordWORDWord32Word2Aa
        /// Word Word ID Word 1 Word WORD Word 32 Word 2 Aa
        /// 
        /// wordWordIDWord1WordWORDWord32Word2A
        /// Word Word ID Word 1 Word WORD Word 32 Word 2 A
        /// </example>
        public static string SplitCamelCase(this string input)
        {
            if (input == null) return null;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return "";

            var separated = input;

            separated = SplitCamelCaseRegex.Replace(separated, @" $1").Trim();

            //Set ALL CAPS words
            if (_SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords.Any())
                foreach (var word in _SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords)
                    separated = SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords_Regexes[word].Replace(separated, word.ToUpper());

            //Capitalize first letter
            var firstChar = separated.First(); //NullOrWhiteSpace handled earlier
            if (char.IsLower(firstChar))
                separated = char.ToUpper(firstChar) + separated.Substring(1);

            return separated;
        }

        private static readonly Regex SplitCamelCaseRegex = new Regex(@"
            (
                (?<=[a-z])[A-Z0-9] (?# lower-to-other boundaries )
                |
                (?<=[0-9])[a-zA-Z] (?# number-to-other boundaries )
                |
                (?<=[A-Z])[0-9] (?# cap-to-number boundaries; handles a specific issue with the next condition )
                |
                (?<=[A-Z])[A-Z](?=[a-z]) (?# handles longer strings of caps like ID or CMS by splitting off the last capital )
            )"
            , RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
        );

        private static readonly string[] _SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords =
            (WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords"] ?? "")
                .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(a => a.ToLowerInvariant().Trim())
                .ToArray()
                ;

        private static Dictionary<string, Regex> _SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords_Regexes;
        private static Dictionary<string, Regex> SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords_Regexes
        {
            get
            {
                if (_SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords_Regexes == null)
                {
                    _SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords_Regexes = new Dictionary<string,Regex>();
                    foreach(var word in _SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords)
                        _SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords_Regexes.Add(word, new Regex(@"\b" + word + @"\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
                }

                return _SplitCamelCase_AllCapsWords_Regexes;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use C# extension methods

```
        public static string SpacesFromCamel(this string value)
        {
            if (value.Length > 0)
            {
                var result = new List<char>();
                char[] array = value.ToCharArray();
                foreach (var item in array)
                {
                    if (char.IsUpper(item) && result.Count > 0)
                    {
                        result.Add(' ');
                    }
                    result.Add(item);
                }

                return new string(result.ToArray());
            }
            return value;
        }
```

Then you can use it like

```
var result = "TestString".SpacesFromCamel();
```

Result will be

> Test String

Comment: This actually creates a space at the beginning, fixed the code

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ:

```
var chars = ControlSelectionType.NotApplicable.ToString().SelectMany((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? new char[] { ' ', x } : new char[] { x });

Console.WriteLine(new string(chars.ToArray()));
```

Comment: You should move back to coding with C\C++ :D - way too dirty for C#

Comment: Well I did state that it was a quick and dirty hack. Here's a cleaner LINQ version.

Comment: This doesn't handle Acroynms in the text like AMACharter, returns 'A M A Charter' not 'AMA Charter

Answer (score 3):

I also have an `enum` which I had to separate. In my case this method solved the problem-

```
string SeparateCamelCase(string str)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(str[i]))
        {
            str = str.Insert(i, " ");
            i++;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum ControlSelectionType    
{   
    NotApplicable = 1,   
    SingleSelectRadioButtons = 2,   
    SingleSelectDropDownList = 3,   
    MultiSelectCheckBox = 4,   
    MultiSelectListBox = 5   
} 
public class NameValue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}    
public static List<NameValue> EnumToList<T>(bool camelcase)
        {
            var array = (T[])(Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>()); 
            var array2 = Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).ToArray<string>(); 
            List<NameValue> lst = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (lst == null)
                    lst = new List<NameValue>();
                string name = "";
                if (camelcase)
                {
                    name = array2[i].CamelCaseFriendly();
                }
                else
                    name = array2[i];
                T value = array[i];
                lst.Add(new NameValue { Name = name, Value = value });
            }
            return lst;
        }
        public static string CamelCaseFriendly(this string pascalCaseString)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex("(?<=[a-z])(?<x>[A-Z])|(?<=.)(?<x>[A-Z])(?=[a-z])");
            return r.Replace(pascalCaseString, " ${x}");
        }

//In  your form 
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = GeneralClass.EnumToList<ControlSelectionType  >(true); ;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value";

            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution from Eoin Campbell works good except if you have a Web Service.

You would need to do the Following as the Description Attribute is not serializable.

```
[DataContract]
public enum ControlSelectionType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Not Applicable")]
    NotApplicable = 1,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Single Select Radio Buttons")]
    SingleSelectRadioButtons = 2,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Completely Different Display Text")]
    SingleSelectDropDownList = 3,
}


public static string GetDescriptionFromEnumValue(Enum value)
{
    EnumMemberAttribute attribute = value.GetType()
        .GetField(value.ToString())
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false)
        .SingleOrDefault() as EnumMemberAttribute;
    return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And if you don't fancy using regex - try this:

```
public static string SeperateByCamelCase(this string text, char splitChar = ' ') {

        var output = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            var c = text[i];

            //if not the first and the char is upper
            if (i > 0 && char.IsUpper(c)) {

                var wasLastLower = char.IsLower(text[i - 1]);

                if (i + 1 < text.Length) //is there a next
                {
                    var isNextUpper = char.IsUpper(text[i + 1]);

                    if (!isNextUpper) //if next is not upper (start of a word).
                    {
                        output.Append(splitChar);
                    }
                    else if (wasLastLower) //last was lower but i'm upper and my next is an upper (start of an achromin). 'abcdHTTP' 'abcd HTTP'
                    {
                        output.Append(splitChar);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //last letter - if its upper and the last letter was lower 'abcd' to 'abcd A'
                    if (wasLastLower)
                    {
                        output.Append(splitChar);
                    }
                }
            }

            output.Append(c);
        }


        return output.ToString();

    }
```

Passes these tests, it doesn't like numbers but i didn't need it to.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void ToCamelCaseTest()
    {

        var testData = new string[] { "AAACamel", "AAA", "SplitThisByCamel", "AnA", "doesnothing", "a", "A", "aasdasdAAA" };
        var expectedData = new string[] { "AAA Camel", "AAA", "Split This By Camel", "An A", "doesnothing", "a", "A", "aasdasd AAA" };

        for (int i = 0; i < testData.Length; i++)
        {
            var actual = testData[i].SeperateByCamelCase();
            var expected = expectedData[i];
            Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple version similar to some of the above, but with logic to not auto-insert the separator (which is by default, a space, but can be any char) if there's already one at the current position.

Uses a `StringBuilder` rather than 'mutating' strings.

```
public static string SeparateCamelCase(this string value, char separator = ' ') {

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var lastChar = separator;

    foreach (var currentChar in value) {

        if (char.IsUpper(currentChar) && lastChar != separator)
            sb.Append(separator);

        sb.Append(currentChar);

        lastChar = currentChar;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Example:

```
Input  : 'ThisIsATest'
Output : 'This Is A Test'

Input  : 'This IsATest'
Output : 'This Is A Test' (Note: Still only one space between 'This' and 'Is')

Input  : 'ThisIsATest' (with separator '_')
Output : 'This_Is_A_Test'
```

Answer (score 2):

#JustSayNoToRegex

Takes a C# identifier, with uderscores and numbers, and converts it to space-separated string.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SplitOnCase(this string identifier)
    {
        if (identifier == null || identifier.Length == 0) return string.Empty;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (identifier.Length == 1) sb.Append(char.ToUpperInvariant(identifier[0]));

        else if (identifier.Length == 2) sb.Append(char.ToUpperInvariant(identifier[0])).Append(identifier[1]);

        else {
            if (identifier[0] != '_') sb.Append(char.ToUpperInvariant(identifier[0]));
            for (int i = 1; i < identifier.Length; i++) {
                var current = identifier[i];
                var previous = identifier[i - 1];

                if (current == '_' && previous == '_') continue;

                else if (current == '_') {
                    sb.Append(' ');
                }

                else if (char.IsLetter(current) && previous == '_') {
                    sb.Append(char.ToUpperInvariant(current));
                }

                else if (char.IsDigit(current) && char.IsLetter(previous)) {
                    sb.Append(' ').Append(current);
                }

                else if (char.IsLetter(current) && char.IsDigit(previous)) {
                    sb.Append(' ').Append(char.ToUpperInvariant(current));
                }

                else if (char.IsUpper(current) && char.IsLower(previous) 
                    && (i < identifier.Length - 1 && char.IsUpper(identifier[i + 1]) || i == identifier.Length - 1)) {
                        sb.Append(' ').Append(current);
                }

                else if (char.IsUpper(current) && i < identifier.Length - 1 && char.IsLower(identifier[i + 1])) {
                    sb.Append(' ').Append(current);
                }

                else {
                    sb.Append(current);
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
```

Tests:

```
[TestFixture]
static class HelpersTests
{
    [Test]
    public static void Basic()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo", "foo".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo", "_foo".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo", "__foo".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo", "___foo".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo 2", "foo2".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo 23", "foo23".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo 23 A", "foo23A".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo 23 Ab", "foo23Ab".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo 23 Ab", "foo23_ab".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo 23 Ab", "foo23___ab".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo 23", "foo__23".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo Bar", "Foo_bar".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo Bar", "Foo____bar".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("AAA", "AAA".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo A Aa", "fooAAa".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo AAA", "fooAAA".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Foo Bar", "FooBar".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("Mn M", "MnM".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("AS", "aS".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("As", "as".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("A", "a".SplitOnCase());
        Assert.AreEqual("_", "_".SplitOnCase());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console
            .WriteLine(
                SeparateByCamelCase("TestString") == "Test String" // True
            );
    }

    public static string SeparateByCamelCase(string str)
    {
        return String.Join(" ", SplitByCamelCase(str));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByCamelCase(string str) 
    {
        if (str.Length == 0) 
            return new List<string>();

        return 
            new List<string> 
            { 
                Head(str) 
            }
            .Concat(
                SplitByCamelCase(
                    Tail(str)
                )
            );
    }

    public static string Head(string str)
    {
        return new String(
                    str
                        .Take(1)
                        .Concat(
                            str
                                .Skip(1)
                                .TakeWhile(IsLower)
                        )
                        .ToArray()
                );
    }

    public static string Tail(string str)
    {
        return new String(
                    str
                        .Skip(
                            Head(str).Length
                        )
                        .ToArray()
                );
    }

    public static bool IsLower(char ch) 
    {
        return ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z';
    }
}
```

[See sample online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MAvRFO)