# Get word from string that is a bunch of fused words

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a word from a bunch of randomtyped characters or words, for example, I want check if the word `dog` exists in the following string:

```
string animal = "MyNewdogIsVeryPlayful";
```

How would I manage this?

Comment: That is a requirement, not a question.

Comment: How do you mean, you want the word `dog`? Do you want a boolean response to tell you whether the string contains "dog" or not?

Comment: @Kjartan Yes, that would be my objective.

Comment: Is it always `camelCase`? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried using IsMatch, Contains and Regex.

Comment: @StevenBorges Show your attempts next time and you won't get downvoted. Otherwise this appears as a "do it for me" kind of question.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question so it reflects what you really wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string animal = "MyNewdogIsVeryPlayful";
bool isDogContained = animal.Contains("dog");
```

Assuming you want to check for different animals, you could create an extension method (place it in a separate static class):

```
public static bool Contains(this string listOfAnimals, string animalToSearchFor){
    return listOfAnimals.Contains(animalToSearchFor);
}
```

That will let you do e.g.:

```
bool doesItContainLion = "MyNewdogIsVeryPlayful".Contains("lion");
```

Comment: I know. But then, that was what he wanted! :) (See my comment below the OP).

Comment: I think the OP said in his comments that this is exactly what he wants.

Comment: Yes it's what I wanted, thanks Kjartan, at first it didn't work for me, but then I realized I used the wrong variable in my code, so I thought .Contains didn't actualy work!

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
string animal = "MyNewdogIsVeryPlayful";
bool containsDog = animal.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("DOG");
```

This will work regardless of the casing of the original string.

If the string is camel-cased, and you want to split the string up to get the constituent words, have a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5796427/2609288).